# Please help me with my Ruby script (ruby 2.0.0p481)

Tags: ruby, json

I am writing a ruby script to accept an input file that is a CSV. I want to make a pretty JSON file. I feel that I am so close but I can't seem to get there. My original project was in JS but the requirements have changed to make it a Ruby file.

My input file looks like this

item id,description,price,cost,price_type,quantity_on_hand,size_1_name,size_1_price,size_2_name,size_2_price,size_3_name,size_3_price

one thing to note is that some of the values in the CSV file maybe missing because it doesn't exist.

```
require 'csv'
require 'json'

def is_int(str)
  return !!(str =~ /^[-+]?[1-9]([0-9]*)?$/)
end

lines = CSV.open(ARGV[0],{:col_sep => ","}).readlines
# remove first entry of the lines array 
keys = lines.shift  

lines.each do |values|
     # convert the line into a hash and transform string into int
     #hash=Hash[keys.zip(values.map{|val| is_int(val) ? val.to_i : val}) ]
     hash = keys.zip(values.map{ val})
     # Write a file with the hash results
     File.open("#{hash['NAME']}.json", "w") do |f|
        f.write JSON.pretty_generate [hash]
     end
end
```

The output I am trying to get is

```
[
  {
    id: 111010,
    description: 'Coffee',
    price: 1.25,
    cost: 0.80,
    price_type: 'system',
    quantity_on_hand: 100000,
    modifiers: [
      {
        name: 'Small',
        price: -0.25
      },{
        name: 'Medium',
        price: 0.00
      },{
        name: 'Large',
        price: 0.30
      }
    ]
```

the version of Ruby I'm using is 2.0.0p481

```
Error was

usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/csv.rb:1254:in `initialize': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/csv.rb:1254:in `open'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/csv.rb:1254:in `open'
    from stockimporter.rb:8:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What is your question? Do you get an error?

Comment: added the error to the question. I forgot to do that. Sorry

Comment: I don't have time to look into this, but I suspect that `ARGV[0]` is evaluating to `nil`. Add a `p ARGV[0]` line just before the call to `open` to make sure.

Comment: You're right. It did resolve the nil but is now saying rb:17:in `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError) which is line 17 >>"File.open("#{hash['NAME']}.json", "w") do |f| <<

Comment: Can you `put` your `hash`? It seems to be expecting an integer

Comment: @softwareisfun, The thing you call hash is actually an array--the error is saying that ruby cannot convert 'NAME' into an integer index.  Try this: `hash = [1, 2]
puts hash['NAME']` zip() returns an array--not a hash.

Comment: Also, this line `hash = keys.zip(values.map{ val}` will produce an error--because val is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

csv.csv:

```
id,description,price,cost,price_type,quantity_on_hand,size_1_name,size_1_price,size_2_name,size_2_price,size_3_name,size_3_price
111010,Coffee,1.25,0.80,system,10000,Small,-0.25,Medium,0.00,Large,0.30
111011,Tea,1.00,0.50,system,100,Small,-0.10,Medium,0.00,Large,0.10
111012,MissingInfo,1.00,0.50,,100,,,Medium,,Large,0.10
```

...

```
require 'csv'
require 'pp'
require 'json'

csv_options = {
  headers: true,  #skip first line of csv file
  converters: [:numeric]  #convert strings that look like integers or floats to integers or floats
}

results = []

CSV.foreach('csv.csv', csv_options) do |row|
  record = Hash[row.take(6)]

  modifiers = [
    {
      name: row["size_1_name"],
      price: row["size_1_price"]
    },
    {
      name: row["size_2_name"],
      price: row["size_2_price"],
    },
    {
      name: row["size_3_name"],
      price: row["size_3_price"]
    }
  ]

  record['modifiers'] = modifiers
  results << record
end

pp results


--output:--
[{"id"=>111010,
  "description"=>"Coffee",
  "price"=>1.25,
  "cost"=>0.8,
  "price_type"=>"system",
  "quantity_on_hand"=>10000,
  "modifiers"=>
   [{:name=>"Small", :price=>-0.25},
    {:name=>"Medium", :price=>0.0},
    {:name=>"Large", :price=>0.3}]},
 {"id"=>111011,
  "description"=>"Tea",
  "price"=>1.0,
  "cost"=>0.5,
  "price_type"=>"system",
  "quantity_on_hand"=>100,
  "modifiers"=>
   [{:name=>"Small", :price=>-0.1},
    {:name=>"Medium", :price=>0.0},
    {:name=>"Large", :price=>0.1}]},
 {"id"=>111012,
  "description"=>"MissingInfo",
  "price"=>1.0,
  "cost"=>0.5,
  "price_type"=>nil,
  "quantity_on_hand"=>100,
  "modifiers"=>
   [{:name=>nil, :price=>nil},
    {:name=>"Medium", :price=>nil},
    {:name=>"Large", :price=>0.1}]}]



json = JSON.pretty_generate(results)
puts json


--output:--
[
  {
    "id": 111010,
    "description": "Coffee",
    "price": 1.25,
    "cost": 0.8,
    "price_type": "system",
    "quantity_on_hand": 10000,
    "modifiers": [
      {
        "name": "Small",
        "price": -0.25
      },
      {
        "name": "Medium",
        "price": 0.0
      },
      {
        "name": "Large",
        "price": 0.3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 111011,
    "description": "Tea",
    "price": 1.0,
    "cost": 0.5,
    "price_type": "system",
    "quantity_on_hand": 100,
    "modifiers": [
      {
        "name": "Small",
        "price": -0.1
      },
      {
        "name": "Medium",
        "price": 0.0
      },
      {
        "name": "Large",
        "price": 0.1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 111012,
    "description": "MissingInfo",
    "price": 1.0,
    "cost": 0.5,
    "price_type": null,
    "quantity_on_hand": 100,
    "modifiers": [
      {
        "name": null,
        "price": null
      },
      {
        "name": "Medium",
        "price": null
      },
      {
        "name": "Large",
        "price": 0.1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

You could also do it like this:

```
CSV.foreach('csv.csv', csv_options) do |row|
  record = Hash[row.take(6)]
  price_adjustments = row.drop(6)

  #             [["size_1_name", "Small"], ["size_1_price", -0.25]]
  #            |---------------------------------------------------|                          
  #                                      ^
  #                                      |
  modifiers = price_adjustments.each_slice(2).map do |size_price|
    size_price.first[0] = 'name'
    size_price.last[0] = 'price'
    Hash[size_price]
  end

  p modifiers  #e.g. [{"name"=>"Small", "price"=>-0.25}, {"name"=>"Medium", "price"=>0.0}, {"name"=>"Large", "price"=>0.3}]

  record['modifiers'] = modifiers
  results << record
end

pp results
```

Comment: thanks. the output must look like the one in my example. someone ese takes the file then does stuff. the other persons code isnt going to changee. its my node code that needs to be made into ruby

Comment: @softwareisfun, Your example output is not json.  I'm going to have to let you go now.  Good luck.